# Kotlin check parameter's type

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

When working with Java's reflection I can do something like this:
`method.getParameterTypes()[i]` which gives me parameter's `i` type (`Class`).

How can I achieve this using Kotlin's `KCallable`?
I've tried doing something like this: `callable.parameters[i].type` but the only thing I found was `type.javaType` but it returns `Type` which didn't help me at all. I also tried `parameters[i].kind` but that didn't help me at all.

How can I do Java's `method.getParameterTypes()` using Kotlin's `KCallable`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Kotlin 1.1+,

1) You have `kotlin-reflect`, then you should use `callable.parameters[i].type.jvmErasure.java`.

2) You don't have `kotlin-reflect`, then go to 3)

If you are using older version, I strongly suggest you to port your code to 1.1. If for some reason you have to stick to the older one, go to 3),

3) You should first add this piece of code, which calculates the rawtype of a given `java.lang.reflect.Type`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*

val Type.rawtype: Class<*>
    get() = when (this) {
        is Class<*> -> this
        is ParameterizedType -> rawType as Class<*>
        is GenericArrayType -> genericComponentType.rawtype.asArrayType()
        is TypeVariable<*> ->
            this.bounds[0]?.rawtype ?: Any::class.java // <--- A bug of smart cast here, forcing the use of "this."
        is WildcardType -> lowerBounds[0].rawtype
        else -> throw AssertionError("Unexpected type of Type: " + javaClass)
    }

fun Class<*>.asArrayType() = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(this, 0).javaClass
```

then just call `callable.parameters[i].type.javaType.rawtype`.

Comment: I have Kotlin 1.1.2 though the first way throws the following exception: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeImpl.getClassifier()Lkotlin/reflect/KClassifier;`

Comment: That would be werid. Try with a clean download. The above code work fine on my end. Also check if some of your library depends on older kotlin and it messed up your classes.

Comment: After all, it's an `AbstractMethodError`, which typically means there is a something very bad happening outside the source code.

Comment: It kind of works. My project has 2 modules but only in one of them I got `kotiln-reflect` artifact (I use Maven). If I test both of them at the same time I get the exception but if a test only the one with `kotlin-reflect` it works fine. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds quite werid. Maybe the kotlin version of your two projects are different? Or it won't bug when testing them together. reflect and stdlib of the same version should be compatible with each other even if they are included multiple times in the classpath. Anyway, I updated my anwser to include the warning about the `kotlin-reflect`.

Comment: Both modules have a common parent in which there is the `kotlin-stdlib` as well as `kotlin-runtime` so these have the same version for sure. Double checked `kotlin-reflect` and it has 1.1.2 too. It's bugging only when I test two modules at once. If I test only the module with `kotlin-reflect` everything works 100% fine. May it be a IDE bug?

Comment: I don't know. However I do think the situation is werid enough to open a seperate question. It will attract more people among whom someone knows what's going on may occur.